# On duplicate, conditional update, not working

Tags: mysql, query, insert, json

I have a table with two columns : id(int), data(text)

data holds an array of strings. I want to insert strings into it, if they're not already present.

Searched a bit, came up with this :

```sql
INSERT INTO schema_name.table_name(id, data) VALUES(1, '["3"]') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE data= IF(JSON_CONTAINS(data,'3', '$'), JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(data, '$', '3'), data)
```

It does not insert "3" into data, whether or not it's already present. It doesn't return an error.
I'm wondering how should I do it, and why this does not work

Thank you

Comment: It might help if you created a reproducible [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). Also, is this question really about both SQL Server and MySQL?

Comment: ON DUPLICATE fires **ONLY** as a reaction on some UNIQUE constraint violation. What **unique index** in your table allows to detect that the value `'["3"]'` is a duplicate?

Comment: Ugh.  JSON is grossly inefficient to manipulate.  Can't you lay out the schema some other way?  Explain what kind of data you are storring there.

Comment: @RickJames I have two tables. One to store (message_id, message_text), the other one to store the message_ids for sent by a specific user(user_id, message_id_list).
This is to make searching all messages of a user more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. There were two issues :

1. For some reasons, if I want to check if string "3" is present in the array, I need to give JSON_CONTAINS '"3"' as second argument, and not '3'
   However, for JSON_ARRAY_APPEND '3' is enough.
2. I had my IF statement's 2nd and 3rd argument switched up. As @Niyaz noted it.

This query worked :

```sql
INSERT INTO schema_name.table_name(id, data) VALUES(1, '["3"]')

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE data = IF(JSON_CONTAINS(data, '"3"', '$'), data, JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(data, '$', '3'))
```

Will set this as AA when the 2 days wait period is over

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget to add `!`, check the below example it adds any new number except [1-4].

```
SET @list = '["1","2","3","4"]';
# try existing number(1,2,3, and 4), they won't add to the list
SET @item_list = '["5"]'; 
SET @item = '5';


select IF(!JSON_CONTAINS(@list,@item_list, '$'), JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(@list, '$', @item), @list);
```

Comment: You're right. I'll switch the IF statement 2nd and 3rd argument which will be the same as adding a !

Thanks :) I also had a second issue which I explained in my 2nd post

Answer (score 1):

> the other one to store the message_ids for sent by a specific user(user_id, message_id_list).

That is a simply one-to-many relationship between Users and Messages.  It is easily and efficiently implemented by having `user_id` in the `messages` table *and* have `INDEX(user_id)` on that table.  No JSON (for this purpose); not slow.

Comment: The thing is user_id here will be a non-unique index. If I do SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_id=1, it will take 40~ seconds to perform. Where if SELECT the different message_ids it will be instant.

But I can't know what message_ids I need to fetch unless I have another table listing a user's message_ids

Unless I'm misunderstanding something here.

Comment: 40 Seconds??  How many rows in the table?  How many rows in the result set?  Do you have the INDEX I suggested?  Please provide the `SELECT` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Oh I get it now. I first thought that all columns had an index, and that for some reason if they were not UNIQUE index then it would just take a lot of time(I know very little about SQL databases). I see now how to add an INDEX.
It's created. And the searching is instant, thank you very much ! I feel like I discovered a new superpower lol